# Angularjs ng-class expression contains substring compared with current day

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

As you can see in the following code, I have a table, filled with various rows by ng-repeat and a JSON.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="roll in filtering(JSON) | orderBy:[sortType,'Cutoff']:sortReverse | filter:q as results" ng-class="{ 'danger': roll.Status == 'Running', 'success': roll.Status == 'Done', 'strike': roll.Days == 'MON'}" ng-if="roll.Group == groupType || groupType == 'yes'">
        <td>{{ roll.Status }}</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

One row contains the variable 'Days' which has occurrences like f.e. *MON* for Monday or *MONTUEWED* for Monday till Wednesday or *TUETHUFRI* for Tuesday and Thursday till Friday.

I want to use the ng-class element (as can be seen above and in a snip below):

```
'strike': roll.Days == 'MON'
```

to check if my Days String (in roll.Days) for each row contains the current day (if possible something like Format(Now) to MON or TUE etc.) and apply the 'strike' css (for Information purpose: the row will then change to italic text and the background will be colored grey)

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: set current day in scope variable in controller and use that for comparison. Read javascript Date docs to find how to get current day and use built in angular date filter to parse it

Comment: fulfils a lot of my requirements, but how to check for the substring?

Comment: what substring? not clear what you are asking

Comment: how about `row.Days.indexOf(today) >= 0`?

Comment: @charlietfl: my roll.Days can have MON as well as MONTUE, if a check if MON == MONTUE i will get a problem

Comment: did you try indexOf() as suggested?

Comment: Also ... could set a prototype or property on objects that returns boolean for `is_today` and simplify the view

Comment: indexOf requests an Array like e.g. ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "FRI"] i think, isn't it? I need something that checks all letters for a letter sequence like MONTUE.

Comment: due to no answers: here you can find a fiddle, using indexOf, but in the example not every instance of "TUE" is found: http://jsfiddle.net/ARK5q/293/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of the commentators I found a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ARK5q/298/

```
ng-repeat="jobSet in dashboard.currentWork" 
    ng-class="{'approved': jobSet.indexOf(selectedForApproval) >= 0}"
```

Whereas the App Controller must be like:

var app = angular.module("DemoApp", [])

```
app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.dashboard = {
    currentWork: [
        'MON',
        'MONTUE',
        'MONTUE',
        'MONTUEFRI',
        'TUEFRI',
        'TUE',
        'WED',
        'WED',
    ]
};
    $scope.selectedForApproval = ['TUE'];
});
```